# How to make compiler to search for only specific files in include directory and exclude the rest in that particular directory

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, include

let me give you some example of my problem. Let's say I have two directory, dir1 & dir2. Inside each of these directories will have two files: dir1/fileA.h & dir1/fileB.h. The dir2 will have files with the same name dir2/fileA.h & dir2/fileB.h, but their contents are different with those in dir1. My problem arise if I want to use dir1/fileA.h & dir2/fileB.h. If I include dir1 first then followed by dir2

```
           INCLUDE_DIRS += \ dir1 \

                             dir2
```

then the compiler will refer to both fileA.h & fileB.h in dir1 only, and ignore the files in dir2, or vice versa if I put the dir2 first before dir1. Again, is there any solution to make the compiler to look for fileA.h in dir1 but fileB.h in dir2?

Comment: Do `#include "dir1/fileA.h"`. Or, use symbolic (or hard) links or just plain old copies to build a directory that has just the files you want in it. What you want to do is outside the scope of what the compiler can deal with and you have to solve it outside the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. But suppose that your `dir1` and `dir2` 
have a common base directory `root`, such that

```
   dir1 = the-root/path1
   dir2 = the-root/path2
```

Then, use `-Ithe-root` as compile option in your `Makefile`

```
   target: source.c
         gcc -Ithe-root source.c ...
```

and include in your C file:

```
   #include "path1/fileA.h"
   #include "path2/fileA.h"
```

or whatever you feel like it.